# What happens when event is triggered

Tags: javascript, dom

Maybe this question is not in so 'problem/solved' version, but i'm still curious : 
In javascript, when we make hypothetical event

```
    _addEvent(window,"resize",
            function (){
                location.reload(); // needed to reload page when it is resized
                //somefunctions
            }
        );
```

and do some style configuration with in event [in somefunctions part ] , when page resizes, does the new [resized] page inherit in some way modified javascript and css from before and then goes to the event after it is resized again?

Just curious in what stages DOM object goes trough when page is resized, and than resized again.

Real world example:  resizing browser window on computer to fit half of the screen, then resizing it to a full screen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a page is resized, the page contents is not changed by the browser.  The window size is changed, the browser will run layout again on the existing content to decide where things should be displayed in the newly sized window and then the resize event will be triggered.

If the resize handler makes changes to the DOM, then the browser will again decide if new layout needs to be redone, but this doesn't trigger another resize event.

If you are doing a `location.reload()` in the resize handler (which sounds like a **horrible idea** by the way), then you are loading a whole new page and the newly loaded page will just load into the current window size.  There will not be another resize event for the newly loaded page unless the window size is again changed by the user.

`location.reload()` does not inherit anything except cookies and localStorage from the previous page.  The content is reloaded from scratch (some of it may come from cache), the browser parses that from scratch and starts a new page over again.  It would be like pressing F5 in the browser to reload the page.

Comment: thanks for the heads up! :D i just copied that from some code, did not even notice :o 

but if i have some div, that is in full screen view on the left, and on half screen view on the right and smaller in dimension, and all that is governed by js ( no css included ) is it still the same process ?

Comment: @Danilo - Same process.  `resize` events occur the same no matter what your JS is doing.  You can use JS to position or resize elements in a `resize` event.  That doesn't change anything about the resize event.  That resize event ONLY occurs when the containing window is resized.  It has nothing to do with content being changed.